# Proof regarding divisibility and set theory

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, divisibility

I need to prove the following statement :

$$\{x \in \mathbb{Z}:2∣ x\} \cap \{x \in \mathbb{Z}:9∣x \}\subset  \{x\in \mathbb{Z}:6∣x\}$$

Solution :

Verbally this means, that every whole number which is divisible by both 2 and 9, is divisible by 6 as well. So this intersection forms a set, which has an element *x*. Lets assume that x is divisible by both 2 and 9.

$$x = 2 ⋅9 ⋅ k ,  k∈Z$$

$$\frac{x}{2 ⋅ 9}=k$$

$$\frac{x}{18}=k$$

In other words, if *x* is divisible by 2 and 9, it's the same as saying it's divisible by 18. Let's now show that *x* is divisible by 6 as well.

$$\frac{3⋅x}{3⋅6}=3k$$

$$\frac{x}{6}=3k$$

This shows, that every element *x* of our intersection is also an element of the rightwise set, and this intersection is, by definition, a subset of that set.

Comment: More succinctly, if $9|x$ and $2|x$, then $3|x$ and $2|x$, so $6|x$

Comment: An interjection is an inserted expression, such as “Oh!”

Comment: @J.W.Tanner and suddenly, [schoolhouse rock started playing in my head](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_e24kdjdbtw).

Comment: Thanks for the great link, @JMoravitz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$x\in LHS$$

$x=2k_1$ and $x=9k_2$

Since $2$and $9$ are relatively prime we have $x=18 k_3$

Thus $$x=6(3k_3)=6k_4$$

Thus $$x\in RHS. $$

Comment: Are you suggesting this is the correct way or equivalent to what I have done? I'm not particularly well versed in relatively prime numbers.

Comment: Your proof is fine. The point that I try to make is that since $2$ and $9$ do not have any common prime factor, if a number is a multiple of $2$ and a multiple of $9$ it has to be a multiple of $18$